# How to get user current Location in angularJs?

Tags: angularjs

How to get user current Location in angularJs?
   In this my requirement is i need to different controller and service,in service we need to write ajax call and in controller we need to pass thee data i mean parameters and get response, user location should be displayed in html page?

Answer (score -1):

You can use $state

Here's the documentation for that [UI-Router](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router)

Comment: Care to comment back whoever down-voted this? Be more constructive than just down vote, so us newbies can learn.

Answer (score -1):

Use

> $location.path();

Remember to inject $location into Angularjs Controller